# React Native, sending list through a component with withNavigation

Tags: react-native

My question is somewhat unique than many other similar ones: I want to pass some list to another screen through a (functional) component. It doesn't work.

App.js has:

```
const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
    locationAllFlow: createStackNavigator(
        {
            locationsFlow: createStackNavigator(
                {
                    Locations: { screen: LocationsScreen },
                    Search: { screen: SearchScreen }
                },
                {
                    headerMode: 'none'
                }
            ),
            LocationDetail: LocationDetailScreen
        },
        {
            headerMode: 'none'
        }
    ),
...
```

Then LocationsScreen has:

```
<TitleBar
    title='Locations'
    hasSearch={true}
    list={results.map(result => result.name)}
/>
```

and LocationsScreen has TitlBar as a component:

```
const TitleBar = ({ navigation, title, hasSearch, list }) => {
...
<TouchableOpacity
    style={{ padding: 8, position: 'absolute', right: 4 }}
    onPress={() => {
        console.log('inside onPress: ', list);
        navigation.navigate('Search', { list });
    }}
>
    <MaterialIcons style={styles.titleIcon} name='search' />
</TouchableOpacity>
...
export default withNavigation(TitleBar);
```

and finally, need to go to SearchScreen:

```
const SearchScreen = ({ list }) => {
    console.log('SearchScreen: list.length: ', list);
    return (
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgb(15, 104, 186)', flex: 1 }}>
            <SafeAreaView>
                <FlatList
                    data={list}
                    keyExtractor={item => item}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <TouchableOpacity>
                            <Text>item</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    )}
                />
            </SafeAreaView>
        </View>
    );
};
```

Trouble happens in the SearchScreen: though `inside onPress:` prints list very well, somehow, `SearchScreen: list.length:` prints `undefined`. Why?

Comment: Are you sure your `navigation` isn't undefined? when you do this `const TitleBar = ({ navigation, title, hasSearch, list }) => {`

Comment: Also in case of `react-navigation` , I find my the object passed somewhere here `this.props.navigation.state.params` , `Console.log` the props and see if you are actually receiving them

Comment: well, `navigation` is working well, since it goes to SearchScreen, at least.

Comment: props.navigation.state.params has `list`.

Comment: then, why `{ list }` doesn't work? now, I checked that  `const SearchScreen = props => {` with `data={props.navigation.state.params.list}` works good!

Comment: Problem solved?
You can destructure nested properties hence `{ list }` doesn't work

Comment: oh, yes, Vincius is right. I forgot that `SearchScreen` is NOT a nested component, so need to use `getParam()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list` won't be passed as params to SearchScreen. You should use `navigation.getParam(paramID, defaultValue)` instead

Docs reference: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html